# Show Fullsize Image On Hover

Tags: html, css, scale

i know this is going to be an easy answer for someone but i cant seem to get the hang of it.

what i need is simply to increase the size of an image from 20% size to 100% size upon hovering the mouse over it

i am trying to use CSS to accomplish this using transform scale but im having an issue where white space is left to accomodate the size of the full image.

i would much prefer that the text surrounding the image move responsively as the image scales. from what ive read i should use a seperate container to fix this but i cannot get it to work.

i keep trying different things i read in articles but none have been able to fix my problem.

Here is the css ive been working with. this is the closest ive been able to get to what i want but i still have issues with the whitespace.

```
.procedureimage{
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
display: block;
transform: scale(0.2);
}

.procedureimage:hover{
transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for your HTML?

Comment: sure 

<div class="procedureimage">
        <img src="*filepath*">
    </div>

Comment: Looks like you're changing the size of the containing div but not the img.

Comment: anyone have a solution to this issue?